# Free Hard disk image tool (backup/restore)

Tags: gratis, backup, hard-disk

I need a software to create an image of my hard disk and restore it when needed.

1. Need to be free for non commercial use
2. Can create a disk image into a single file
3. Can restore the single file to the hd
4. Can save the image file into an external usb drive
5. Can create a boot CD/DVD to perform both image backup and restore

I need it to quickly restore the Windows XP installation, free of viruses and other unneded software. I'm using Northon Ghost in a old PC but I need a free software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) will do this

- Need to be free for non commercial use: Its FOSS
- Can create a disk image into a single file: Yes, even with multitple partitions
- Can restore the single file to the hd: Absolutely. backups are no good without restores
- Can save the image file into an external usb drive: Yes
- Can create a boot CD/DVD to perform both image backup and restore: Thats what clonezilla live is

Answer (score 4):

Any live Linux CD can do this. They are both free, and open source. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) are probably the two most popular.

The [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) command can create a copy of a hard drive and save it to a file:

```
dd if=/dev/hda of=/path/to/image
```

Where /dev/hda is the hard drive you want to copy.

To restore from the image:

```
dd if=/path/to/image of=/dev/hda
```

You do need to know the device name of the hard drive you want to copy/restore, which
requires a bit of Unix knowledge.

A full tutorial can be found [here](http://www.linuxweblog.com/dd-image).

This is very low-level and probably not what you're looking for, but I thought I'd share just for the record.

Comment: Nice! But actually I've no Linux SO installed. anyway, very interesting!

Comment: @Seraphim'shost, You don't need Linux installed. The liveCDs are bootable. You can boot off USB too. It will backup and restore Windows or Mac all the same.

Answer (score 4):

[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) should meet your requirements.
Citations from the website matched to your criteria:

1. Private edition free
2. Backup logical drives and partitions to image files
3. Restore images to the same or a different drive
4. While I personally have never dumped disk content to USB, I think this should be ok.
5. Run DriveImage from our Runtime Live CD or a WinPE boot CD-ROM